# MongoDB Scala Driver Pushing to a nested Array

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am having a little bit of trouble properly appending to a nested array using Mongo in Scala. I have done the same operation numerous times in Node.js but for some reason I can not translate it to Scala.

Here is the main "schema":

```
case class Band(
             _id: ObjectId,
             name: String,
             username: String,
             email: String,
             path: String,
             tours: List[Tour],
             merchSets: List[MerchSet],
             facebook: Option[String],
             twitter: Option[String],
             youtube: Option[String],
             instagram: Option[String],
             website: Option[String]
           )

object Band {

  def apply(
         _id: ObjectId,
         name: String,
         username: String,
         email: String,
         path: String,
         tours: List[Tour],
         merchSets: List[MerchSet],
         facebook: Option[String],
         twitter: Option[String],
         youtube: Option[String],
         instagram: Option[String],
         website: Option[String]
       ): Band = new Band(_id,
    name, username, email, path, tours, merchSets, facebook, twitter, 
youtube, instagram, website)

  val bandCodecRegistry: CodecRegistry = 
 fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[Band]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
}
```

As you can see this definition has a ***List of Tours*** where a ***Tour*** is defined as:

```
case class Tour(_id: ObjectId,
            name: String,
            shows: List[Show],
            items: List[Item],
            region: String,
            default_merchset : Option[MerchSet]
           )

 object Tour{
   def apply(_id: ObjectId,
        name: String,
        shows: List[Show],
        items: List[Item],
        region: String,
        default_merchset: Option[MerchSet]
       ): Tour = new Tour(_id, name, shows, items, region, default_merchset)

  val tourCodecRegistry : CodecRegistry = 
      fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[Tour]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)
}
```

I am trying push an Item to the items collection, if it doesn't exist, whenever a new item is created.

Basically the end point receives a **band id**, a **tour name** and bunch of form params which is used to create and push the Item.

**GOAL:** The query needs to find the correct band, and the correct tour from the corresponding tours collection and add the created item to corresponding tour.items

The way I would do this in Node.js is the following:

```
var query = {"_id": id, "tours.name": name}
Band.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    {$push: {"tours.$.items": item}}
  )
```

But this just doesn't work in Scala. And I get no errors at all. The subscription hits the OnComplete case although nothing changes in the DB. OnNext case **doesn't** get hit. Somehow the query completes without errors and without succeeding ...

Here is what I have currently:

```
val add = MongoDataBaseConnector.bands.findOneAndUpdate(and(equal("_id", id),
  equal("tours.name", tour_name)),
  push("tours.items", request.toDomain))
```

I have tried to $ operator in the middle and using addToSet but they don't make any difference.

What is the proper way to go about this?

**Note:** This is the official scala driver, not casbah. How to do this in casbah has been answered numerous times.

Comment: Can you also post the code for companion object for the above case classes ?

Comment: @zenwraight Done. It is only apply and they store the CODECs but still ...

Comment: I feel you need to import play.api.libs.json._ and then have a line like - implicit val format: Format[Band] = Json.format[Band] , so this basically gets a json.obj outof ur case class object and then try pushing it to mongodb . I generally do this way.

Comment: @zenwraight thanks for the suggestion. I am using finatra and have been trying to avoid pulling in play. I have actually narrowed down the problem and realized the query itself is not working. I will update the question shortly with my findings

Comment: @zenwraight turns out I forgot to cast the id to ObjectId() ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to cast the id to ObjectId ... 
The query below works

```
def addTourSpecificMerch(request: NewItemRequest, id: ObjectId, name: String): Unit = {
    val tour_name = name.replace("%20", " ")
    val add = MongoDataBaseConnector.bands.findOneAndUpdate(and(equal("_id", id),
      equal("tours.name", tour_name)),
      addToSet("tours.$.items", request.toDomain))

    add.subscribe(new Observer[Band] {
      override def onNext(result: Band): Unit = println(s"onNext: $result")
      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"onError: $e")
      override def onComplete(): Unit = println("onComplete")
    })
}
```

Comment: Nice fine, I think you can accept ur own post as answer for future people who face similar problem.

Comment: @zenwraight yes but there is a time limit. I can accept it after 24 hours :)